# Simplest possible BAM Scenario

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

I’m trying to set up a very simple BAM scenario within BizTalk Server 2013R2 upon which to build, involving tracking just the time of all incoming messages processed by a port.

To this end I have :

- Within Excel, created an Activity Definition (called
  SimpleReceiveTest) containing a single Item called ReceiveTime of
  type milestone (date/time), and a View Definition (also called
  SimpleReceiveTest) containing just this Activity Definition and Item.
- Imported this BAM definition spreadsheet using bm.exe
- Added view rights to SimpleReceiveTest again using bm.exe
- Launched the Tracking Profile Editor, imported the BAM Activity
  Definition, and mapped *ActivityID = MessageID* and *ReceiveTime =

  PortStartTime* by drag and drop from the Messaging Property Schema, as
  shown below :

  [image]
- Set the Port Mappings for MessageID and PortStartTime to relate to a 
  test Receive Port **ReceivePort1** that I am using for testing.  This is 
  using a pass-through pipeline.
- Saved and applied the above Tracking Profile

It is my understanding that for any messages received on port **ReceivePort1** I should now get a tracking activity created.  However this is not happening – there are no records in any of the BAM tables/views and no data is available within the BAM Portal.

I have tried restarting the hosts, and have verified that the TDDS_FailedTrackingData table is empty, there is nothing relevant in the event log, a Tracking host is running and the SQL Agent Jobs are running.  I have also tried running these jobs manually.

Have I missed something, and am I correct in my expectation that this simple scenario should create tracked activities for any messages passing through the Receive Port?  If so what can I try to further diagnose this?

Answer (score 2):

Now fixed - it's actually a bug in vanilla BizTalk 2013R2 when using a standard pipeline that has been fixed in CU2.

***[FIX: BAM tracking doesn’t work when you use the XMLReceive or a custom pipeline in BizTalk Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/3125071)***

Comment: Yes, you should always be on the latest update (currently CU3), you can find the list of all updates for BizTalk at https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/2555976